# Autoresize multiple subviews

Tags: ios, uiview, subview, autoresizingmask

I have a View say mainView. I have set autoresizeMask property to it.

```
[mainView autoresizingMask];
[mainView setAutoresizingMask : UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[mainView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
```

mainView resizes on orientation change.

I want multiple subViews inside the mainView which should resize when mainView resizes.

```
CGFloat width = mainView.frame.size.width/options.count;
for (int i = 0; i < options.count ; i++) {

    UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [subView setBackgroundColor:[ar objectAtIndex:i]];
    [subView setFrame:CGRectMake(i*width, 0, width, 40)];
    [self addSubview:subView];
    [subView autoresizingMask];
    [subView setAutoresizingMask : UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [subView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];

}
```

The subViews do not resize their width on orientation change.

Also I want single view inside each subView which would always remain in the centre of respective subView

```
for (int i = 0; i < options.count ; i++) {

        UIView *subView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [subView setBackgroundColor:[ar objectAtIndex:i]];
        [subView setFrame:CGRectMake(i*width, 0, width, 40)];
        [self addSubview:subView];
        [subView autoresizingMask];
        [subView setAutoresizingMask : UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
        [subView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];

        UIView *childView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [childView autoresizingMask];
        [childView setAutoresizingMask : UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
        childView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
        childView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [subView addSubview:childView];
        childView.center = subView.center;


    }
```

I am not able to achieve the desired results on rotation.
Could somebody tell me how could I achieve the above requirement?

Comment: Did you know for sure mainView behave correctly when orientation changed?

Comment: Yes, the main view resize on orientation change without reframing.
Is there any correction in the above code to achieve my requirement?